# Regex to count the number of syllables in a text

Tags: java, regex

I searched the whole internet and to my sadness found that there is no correct implementation of count of syllables in a text using regex on the internet. First I would like to clear the definition of a syllable:

Syllables are defined as: a contiguous sequence of vowels, except for a lone "e" at the  end of a word if the word has another set of contiguous vowels, makes up one syllable.   y is considered a vowel.

I used the following regex expression statement (with split in Java):

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Graph {
    private Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> adjLists;
    private int numberOfVertices;
    private int numberOfEdges;

    public Graph(int V){
        adjLists = new HashMap<>(V);
        for(int i=0; i<V; i++){
            adjLists.put(i, new ArrayList<Integer>());
        }
        this.numberOfVertices = V;
        this.numberOfEdges = 0;
    }

    public int getNumberOfEdges(){
        return this.numberOfEdges;
    }
    public int getNumberOfVertices(){
        return this.numberOfVertices;
    }

    public void addVertex(){
        adjLists.put(getNumberOfVertices(), new ArrayList<Integer>());
        this.numberOfVertices++;
    }

    public void addEdge(int u, int v){
        adjLists.get(u).add(v);
        adjLists.get(v).add(u);
        this.numberOfEdges++;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getNeighbours(int u){
        return new ArrayList<Integer>(adjLists.get(u));
    }

    public void printTheGraph() {
        for(Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> list: adjLists.entrySet()){
            System.out.print(list.getKey()+": ");
            for(Integer i: list.getValue()){
                System.out.print(i+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public class AdjacencyListGraphTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("graphData");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(reader);

        int E, V;
        V = in.nextInt();
        E = in.nextInt();
        Graph graph = new Graph(V);
        for(int i=0; i<E; i++){
            int u, v;
            u = in.nextInt();
            v = in.nextInt();
            graph.addEdge(u, v);
        }

        graph.printTheGraph();


    }
}
```

But thet didn't work.
The main problem is to how the last 'e' rule is to be figured out using regex. Only the regex expression would suffice. Thank you.

P.S: **People unknown to the topic please don't point to other stackoverflow questions as none of them has a correct implemented answer.**

Comment: Where does your definition of a syllable come from?

Comment: That definition is clearly incorrect. "Sometimes" has two syllables, "preempt" has two, "Melpomene" has four. Regular expressions are not able to count syllables, you need an NLP toolkit for that.

Comment: He is right the sam edefinition is also given in Wren and Martin.

Comment: This "definition" might work for some words of the English language (should mention the target language, because definitions vary greatly), but only for those that have not been created by concatenating other words, and of course it will break down completely for words imported from other languages.

Comment: "there is no correct implementation of count of syllables in a text using regex": the reason may be that a regex is not the best tool for this task.

Comment: The sentence defining OP’s "syllable" is poorly written making the definition ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you a number of syllables vowels in a word:

```
public int getNumVowels(String word) {

    String regexp = "[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]*[aeiouy]+[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]*";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexp);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(word.toLowerCase());

    int count = 0;

    while (m.find()) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

You can call it on every word in your string array:

```
String[] words = getText().split("\\s+");
for (String word : words ) {
  System.out.println("Word: " + word + ", vowels: " + getNumVowels(word));
}
```